# How can i pass data with navigation in dynamic routing NEXT.JS?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am building an next.js eccomerce app where i am fetching the products data from firebase now i want that when user clicks on any product a new page open with details of that particular product. So i was trying to do this with Link tag but on the product page when i am trying to access the data/object i passed it is not receiving there.

**Code to Send Data**

```
<Link href={{pathname:`/hoodies/${curElm.title}`, query: {name : curElm}}}>
              
              <div className="shadow cursor-pointer">
                <Image src={curElm.images[0]} width={200} height={60} />
                <h1 className="font-semibold">{curElm.brand}</h1>
                <h2>{curElm.title}</h2>
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                  <h3 className="font-semibold">
                    Price: {curElm.price}
                  </h3>                  
                </div>
              </div>
              
</Link>
```

Here i am using Link tag to navigate to product page when user clicks any page and sending data which is an object.

HERE i am trying to receive the data in product page like this

```
 const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const data = searchParams.get("name");
  console.log(data)
```

but in console printing nothing

my app router is like--
[image]

Please guide me how can i do this.

Comment: Please also add the context that you're using the `app` router, not the `pages` router

Comment: sir  please check i have added the router image

Comment: Which folder are those under? `/pages` or `/app`?

Comment: under app folder sir

Comment: You are passing the product data as the name query parameter, but it seems like you are trying to access it using `useSearchParams` . Instead, you should use the `useRouter` hook to access query parameters in a Next.js page. `import { useRouter } from 'next/router';`  [Refer](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get (query string) parameters from the URL in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862600/how-can-i-get-query-string-parameters-from-the-url-in-next-js)

Comment: this is the old way to use router like this this does not work in latest next.js

Comment: as the documentation you have suggested the pages routes while i am using app router

Comment: You need to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592804/how-to-access-query-parameters-in-next-js-13-4-with-the-new-app-router in conjunction with using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374380/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-nextjs-13-with-router-push

Comment: thank you sir it is working. thank you very much for your kind help sir. It mean a Lot really.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the product data as the name query parameter, but it seems like you are trying to access it using `useSearchParams`. Instead, you should use the `useRouter` hook to access query parameters in a Next.js page.

`import { useRouter } from 'next/router';`

```js
const router = useRouter();
const { name } = router.query;
console.log(name);
```

[Read official Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router)

Comment: thank you but the answer is for pages but i am using app router so this is not working in my case